# At what point does cURL automatically populate HTTP headers and how can I get them?

Tags: php, curl

I'm sending a cURL request and populating it with just the URL. The headers that are sent out to the server are populated I'm imagining by cURL, when exactly are these headers populated, I'm guessing, when I call `curl_exec`?

I'm very interested how I can get these headers after they have been populated, in particular the `Host` value. I'm aware of `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`, although this is not the same as `Host`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are set to default values on init and you can view the headers by setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);` It will spit out the request headers (lines prefixed with '>')

Comment: Hello. If I'm not mistaken, this is to output the headers returned by the server. I'm wanting the headers that are sent to the server.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood. You want CURLOPT_VERBOSE then